# How to use time staps in ranges using Bokeh server

Tags: python, bokeh

How should I use time stamps when I use `source.stream` in a bokeh app?

Here is a minimal example of what I'm trying to achieve

```
# test.py
from bokeh.io import curdoc, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import Line, Plot, ColumnDataSource, Range1d
from bokeh.layouts import column
import numpy as np

delta_time = np.timedelta64(1,'s')
start_time = np.datetime64('2017-01-01T00:00:00')

tail_length = 30

timerange = Range1d(start_time - tail_length * delta_time, start_time)
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(time=[start_time], y=[0.5]))
plot = Plot(width=200, height=100, x_range=timerange, y_range=Range1d(0,1))
plot.add_glyph(source, Line(x='time',y='y'))

def callback():
    # update axis
    layout.children[0].x_range.start += delta_time
    layout.children[0].x_range.end += delta_time

    # update data
    source.stream(dict(time=[source.data['time'][-1] + delta_time],
                       y=[np.random.rand()]), tail_length)

layout = column(plot)

curdoc().add_root(layout)

# move 10 datapoints into the sliding window before the server starts
for _ in range(10):
    callback()

# then add a new datapoint each second
curdoc().add_periodic_callback(callback, 1000)
```

When I start the server, using `bokeh serve test.py`, the output shows

[image]

Which indicates that the `callback()` function works as inteded. But after a second, when the `callback` is called from `curdoc().add_periodic_callback`, then it fails to display anything,

[image]

To investigate how `x_range` changes during the callback, I added a print statement `print(layout.children[0].x_range.end, type(layout.children[0].x_range.end))` inside the `callback()` definition. It seems like the type of the `x_range` coordinates stay the same, but for some bizarre reason, it has a different string representation when the callback is called in `curdoc().add_periodic_callback`.

```
2017-12-01 21:54:45,520 Starting Bokeh server version 0.12.11 (running on Tornado 4.5.2)
2017-12-01 21:54:45,522 Bokeh app running at: http://localhost:5006/test
2017-12-01 21:54:45,522 Starting Bokeh server with process id: 22665
# printing the 10 initial callback calls here
2017-01-01T00:00:01 <class 'numpy.datetime64'>
2017-01-01T00:00:02 <class 'numpy.datetime64'>
2017-01-01T00:00:03 <class 'numpy.datetime64'>
2017-01-01T00:00:04 <class 'numpy.datetime64'>
2017-01-01T00:00:05 <class 'numpy.datetime64'>
2017-01-01T00:00:06 <class 'numpy.datetime64'>
2017-01-01T00:00:07 <class 'numpy.datetime64'>
2017-01-01T00:00:08 <class 'numpy.datetime64'>
2017-01-01T00:00:09 <class 'numpy.datetime64'>
2017-01-01T00:00:10 <class 'numpy.datetime64'>
2017-12-01 21:54:47,961 200 GET /test (::1) 31.59ms
2017-12-01 21:54:48,381 101 GET /test/ws?bokeh-protocol-version=1.0&bokeh-session-id=jekHIMP5Eo5kjzDDgdMgqba2bNxjbQEpDcBmgET6aHfL (::1) 0.68ms
2017-12-01 21:54:48,381 WebSocket connection opened
2017-12-01 21:54:48,381 ServerConnection created
# printing callback from curdoc().add_periodic_callback here
1483228810001 seconds <class 'numpy.timedelta64'>
1483228810002 seconds <class 'numpy.timedelta64'>
1483228810003 seconds <class 'numpy.timedelta64'>
```

What is really going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting behavior! As you can see the 10 callbacks in the

```
for _ in range(10):
   callback()
```

loop execute when you hit the URL to the bokeh server, those loop through and calculate then results are returned and WebSocket is connected etc.

After that the ColumnDataSource is all the sudden in the float representation of datetime!

The following code shows how converting the float back to datetime will make the graph "work" again.

Notice that I commented out the loop so I only have to convert the first value.

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import Line, Plot, ColumnDataSource, Range1d
from bokeh.layouts import column
import numpy as np


delta_time = np.timedelta64(1,'s')
start_time = np.datetime64('2017-01-01T00:00:00')

tail_length = 30

timerange = Range1d(start_time - tail_length * delta_time, start_time)

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(time=[start_time], y=[0.5]))
plot = Plot(width=500, height=500, x_range=timerange, y_range=Range1d(0,1))
plot.add_glyph(source, Line(x='time',y='y'))


def callback():
    # update axis
    # convert long to datetime
    layout.children[0].x_range.start = np.datetime64(layout.children[0].x_range.start, 'ms') + delta_time
    layout.children[0].x_range.end = np.datetime64(layout.children[0].x_range.end, 'ms') + delta_time

    # update data
    source.stream(dict(time=[np.datetime64(source.data['time'][-1],'ms') + delta_time],
                       y=[np.random.rand()]), tail_length)

layout = column(plot)
doc = curdoc()
doc.add_root(layout)

#move 10 datapoints into the sliding window before the server starts
# for _ in range(10):
#     callback()

# then add a new datapoint each second
doc.add_periodic_callback(callback, 1000)
```